# Opening directory remotely C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, io, directory

I was able to open a directory on my computer locally but when I deployed my website to GoDaddy, I can't get it open. I am assuming it is some sort of security control. Here are the following actions I made:

- set trust level to full in the web.config
- set security to full control in my C:\ directory

Here is the following code to open a folder created in that directory:

```html
    protected void btnOpenFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Path to the customer's folder
        string FolderPath = @"C:\" + customerId.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0') + " - " + lblName.Text;

        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(FolderPath))
        {
            //Opens the customer's folder
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(FolderPath);
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Must have the Dropbox directory in order to open the customer folder.');</script>");
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can't open local folder/file from web application

Comment: That's not how the web works. The server communicates over HTTP to your browser. HTML, CSS, and JavaScript run in the browser's sandbox and does not have direct access to the user's filesystem. If you need direct access, you'll have to get the user to install some other component on their machine. If you don't need direct access, then you should redesign your application to allow the user to upload and download files from your site using built-in tools

Comment: I see what if the folder is in a Dropbox folder, can I access that? @mason

Comment: I see what if the folder is in a Dropbox folder, can I access that? @Backs

Comment: no, you can't do it. your web application can't access local PC

Comment: Since your want Dropbox, you can use their API's to access their Dropbox. It will get the Internet hosted files instead of what's on their computer.

Comment: I see I haven't learn API yet but I will definitely look into that! Thanks for the advice! @mason